# SilverStripe editing gridfield records of 'far' relation

Tags: orm, silverstripe

Suppose the following:

**class: Team**

```
private static $has_one = array(
    'Coach' => 'Coach'
);
```

**class: Coach**

```
private static $has_many = array(
    'Shifts' => 'Shifts'
);
```

Is it possible to have a `GridField` on **Team** to CRUD records on **Shifts** (*skipping* the coach and directly writing to it's coach's Shifts)?

Comment: Even if it's possible... does it make sense? Normally a ModelAdmin is used to edit related models with one interface.

Comment: I understand your point. However, in my context I think it makes sense: Page has_one Header has_many Slides. I want to CRUD **Slides** on **Page**.

Comment: Can a Coach belong to many Teams? if not you can create the gridfield pulling in $this->Coach()->Shifts() and then set the TeamID on Shift when it is saved.

Comment: @Lorentz Yes, pulling in the records like that makes sense. But what do you eman with *set the TeamID on Shift on save*?

Comment: The `TeamID` field doesn't belong in `Shift` though

Comment: Define a $belongs_to on the Coach to Team and then you can get it on write by using $this->Coach()->TeamID.

Comment: @Lorentz I think this might be the missing piece I'm looking for. Mind posting the exact code for `onBeforeWrite()` to save the record ID into TeamID?

Comment: Theroretically it should be possible, just hand over the right list to the gridfield. There is also a https://github.com/briceburg/silverstripe-pickerfield/blob/master/code/HasOnePickerField.php where you can edit your has_one relation and through that the related has_many.

Comment: The behaviour is similar to silverstirpe/widgets: Page has_one WidgetArea, that has_many Widgets. WidgetArea object is created transparently when first widget is added. This behaviour can be implemented for GridField as well.